# concentration bounds on weighted multinomial sum

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, measure-concentration

Consider i.i.d random vectors $Y_{1},..,Y_{n}$ and they are chosen uniformly at random from $\{e_{1},..,e_{L}\}$ where $e_{i}$ is a $L\times 1$ vector with $i$th component be 1 and the others be 0. Given weights $h=(h_1,h_2,..,h_n)\in R^n$ that satisfy $\sum h_k=0 $, we would like to study the tail probability bounds of $$S^2(h)\triangleq\|\sum_{k=1}^n h_kY_k\|^2_2   $$

1. some simple calculations give $ES^2(h)=\|h\|_2^2+\sum_{k\neq k'}h_kh_{k'}\frac1L=(1-\frac1L)\|h\|_2^2$.  Note that for distinct $k_1,k_2,k_3$, $Y_{k_1}^TY_{k_2}$ and $Y_{k_1}^TY_{k_3}$ are uncorrelated, thus $$Var(S^2(h))=4Var(\sum_{k< k'} h_kh_{k'}Y_k^TY_{k'})   $$ 
   $$=4\sum_{k< k'} h_k^2h_{k'}^2Var(Y_k^TY_{k'})\ $$ $$= 4\sum_{k< k'} h_k^2h_{k'}^2\frac1L(1-\frac1L) \leq\frac{2\|h\|_2^4}{L}(1-\frac1L)$$Then Chebyshev inequality yields $\forall t>0$ $$P(\frac{S^2(h)-ES^2(h)}{ES^2(h)}>t)\leq \frac{Var(S^2(h))}{t^2(ES^2(h))^2}\leq \frac2{t^2(L-1)}$$
2. Direct apply a Bernstein inequality for suprema of empirical process (Thm 8.42 in the book 'Mathematical Introduction to Compressed Sensing')

   **Theorem 8.42** *Let $\cal{F}$ be a countable set of functions $F:R^L\rightarrow R$. Let $Y_1,..,Y_n$ be independent random vectors in $R^L$ such that $E(F(Y_k))=0$ and $F(Y_k)\leq K$ almost surely for all $k\in {1,2,.,,n}$ and for all $F\in \cal{F}$ for some constant K>0. Introduce $$Z=\sup_{F\in \cal{F}}\sum_{k=1}^nF(Y_k)$$ Let $\sigma^2_k>0$ such that $E(F(Y_k)^2)\leq \sigma^2_k$ for all $k\in {1,2,.,,n}$ and for all $F\in \cal{F}$. Then for all $t>0$, $$P(Z>EZ+t)\leq \exp{(-\frac{t^2/2}{\sigma^2 + 2KEZ +tK/3})}$$ where $\sigma^2=\sum_k \sigma^2_k$.*

Back to our problem, we apply this theorem to $\tilde{Y}_k:=h_k(Y_k-EY_k)$, $F_x(\tilde{Y}_k):=<x,\tilde{Y}_k>$ and $\cal{F}$ $ = \{ F_x, x\in Q^L,\|x\|_2=1 , <1,x>=0 \}$. Then $Z$ in the theorem above is exactly our $S(h)$. Further, we can choose $K=(1-\frac1L)|h|_{\infty}$ and $\sigma^2_k=\frac{h^2_K}{L}$ Then we have $$P(S(h)\geq ES(h)+t)\leq \exp(-\frac{t^2/2}{\|h\|^2_2/L+|h|_{\infty}(2ES(h)+t/3)})$$

---

Actually, we are interested in  the tail bound $P(S(h)\geq 1)$ when the weights satisfy $\|h\|^2_2 \asymp \frac{L}{n}$, $|h|_{\infty} \asymp \frac{L}{n}$ and $\frac{L}{n}=o(1)$ From the Bernstein inequality for suprema of emprical process, we have $$P(S(h)\geq 1)\leq \exp(-c_{1}\frac{n}{L})$$ where $c_1$ is some positive universal constant. This bound is not good when $\frac{L}{n}$ goes to zero very slowly. It may be even worse than the bound given by Chebyshev inequality : $$P(S(h)\geq 1)\leq c_2\frac{L}{n^2}$$where $c_2$ is some positive universal constant.  We are aiming at finding some improved exponential tail bound. Specifically, can we get $$P(S(h)\geq 1)\leq C\exp(-cn)$$ for some universal positive constants $C,c$ under the assumption or some stronger assumptions? (This bound improve both the two known bounds and is true if we think those $Y_i's$ are i.i.d multivariate normal with the same convariance matrix with that of the original random vector).

---

From another angle, we would like find some analogue to the inequality  $$P(\|\sum_{k=1}^n h_kX_k\|_2\geq \|h\|_2u)\leq \exp(-\frac{L}{2}(u^2-\log(u^2)-1))$$ for all $u>1$ and $h_1,..,h_n$, where $X_1,..,X_n$ are i.i.d uniformly distributed on the unit sphere $S^{n-1}=\{x\in R^L, \|x\|=1\}$. This inequality can be found here [Thm 4.2 in this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.0494.pdf). The prove of this inequality relies on an extension of the Kintchine inequality to sum of independent random vectors that are rotationally invariant. See here [extension of Kintchine inequality](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Stanislaw_Kwapien/publication/226779758_Best_Khintchine_Type_Inequalities_for_Sums_of_Independent_Rotationally_Invariant_Random_Vectors/links/555b3a6908ae6aea08168e87.pdf) .

---

Any thoughts, comments, references are welcomed! Thanks!

Comment: For the record, at time of writing this question has attracted a vote to close as "unclear what you're asking". I strongly disagree with this reason given